# Is it advisable to get copyright on a research proposal and an academic article before submitting them?

Tags: research-process, paper-submission, copyright

Is it advisable to get copyright on a research proposal and an academic article before submitting them?

Do you think there are some distinctions between the two cases mentioned (a research proposal and a scientific paper).

I refer to legislations of Western countries, mainly.

Comment: What do you mean by "get copyright"? Could you indicate your country, please, maybe along with a brief description what the term "get copyright" entails in your jurisdiction, based upon your understanding?

Comment: Sorry, I am not English mother tongue. I am from Italy.

Comment: I have added the appropriate country-tag to your question. The [WP article on copyright in Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_Italy#Formalities) suggests that "Italian law does not require any copyright formalities such as registration or deposit for copyright to subsist. The Civil Code (Art. 2576) and Law no. 633 (Art. 6) provide that the rights are first acquired upon creation of the work as a particular expression of the intellectual effort." I am not posting this as an answer, though, as I think an answer should refer to (and translate from) the primary source rather ...

Comment: ... than relying only on a shortened translation of the original legislation, and one found on Wikipedia at that. There are various Italian regulars on Academia SE, maybe one of them will write an answer.

Comment: But I am not applying in Italy, but I guess it is the same everywhere, as suggested by Nicole Hamilton

Comment: Well, then please specify the countries that you are referring to in your question. I don't think this question can be answered (at least without any "probablies" and "pretty muchs") without looking specifically at single countries. (And if it is very dissimilar countries, you might want to consider splitting up your question into several individual questions.) Removed the [tag:Italy] tag again.

Comment: but I guess that in each country in Europe works pretty much the same for this. Am I wrong, in your opinion?

Comment: I am not sure. I suppose parts of these laws have been harmonized by EU regulations, but [articles such as this one](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/cs201/projects/2009-10/music-and-copyright/differences.html) or this [map of different freedom of panorama laws in Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Freedom_of_Panorama_in_Europe_NC.svg) seem to suggest interpretation of copyright rules is not always uniform across EU countries, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A copyright exists on your original work from the moment it is created and fixed in a tangible form.  No marking or registration is needed.

Here in the US, this may be helpful:  [Copyright in General](http://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-general.html)

(In 1989, the US became a party to the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention#Adoption_and_implementation), now followed by 171 countries.  So the law here should be similar to where you live.  But check your government's site or with an IP attorney if a lot is at stake.)

Comment: Thank you! I am European, however and I am going to apply to European institutions, while it may happen that I will submit papers to American journals, who knows.

Comment: The US now follows international conventions (we didn't always) so the rules should be pretty close where you live.  But check your own government's site or, if necessary, with an IP attorney if a lot is at stake.

Comment: It's worth noting that some journals will require you to sign over some of your copyright privileges as a prerequisite for publication.